# .scrollTo() modifier doesn't work in VStack

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can read the **`scrollPosition`** correctly, but **`scrollTo()`** doesn't work.

**iOS 17**, **Xcode 15.2**. Reproducible code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PositionTest: View {
    @State private var weathers = Weather.samples
    @State private var scrollPosition: Weather.ID?
    @State private var isTaped: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Scroll Position: " + (scrollPosition ?? "Cupertino"))
            
            if !isTaped {
                CollapsedView(
                    weathers: $weathers,
                    scrollPosition: $scrollPosition,
                    isTaped: $isTaped
                )
            } else {
                ExpandedView(
                    weathers: $weathers,
                    scrollPosition: $scrollPosition,
                    isTaped: $isTaped
                )
            }
            
        }
        .font(.title)
        .fontWeight(.semibold)
        .animation(.default, value: isTaped)
    }
}

#Preview {
    PositionTest()
}

struct CollapsedView: View {
    @Binding var weathers: [Weather]
    @Binding var scrollPosition: Weather.ID?
    @Binding var isTaped: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(weathers) { weather in
                        Text(weather.name)
                            .frame(width: 350, height: 227)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .background(.blue.gradient)
                            .cornerRadius(40)
                            .id(weather.id as Weather.ID?)
                            .onTapGesture { isTaped.toggle() }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition, anchor: .center)
            .onAppear { proxy.scrollTo(scrollPosition, anchor: .center) }
        }
    }
}

struct ExpandedView: View {
    @Binding var weathers: [Weather]
    @Binding var scrollPosition: Weather.ID?
    @Binding var isTaped: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(weathers) { weather in
                        Text(weather.name)
                            .frame(width: 250, height: 227)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .background(.indigo.gradient)
                            .clipShape(.circle)
                            .id(weather.id as Weather.ID?)
                            .onTapGesture { isTaped.toggle() }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition, anchor: .center)
            .onAppear { proxy.scrollTo(scrollPosition, anchor: .center) }
        }
    }
}

struct Weather: Identifiable {
    var id: String { name }
    let name: String
    let temp: Int
    
    static let samples = [
        Weather(name: "Cupertino", temp: 12),
        Weather(name: "New York", temp: 13),
        Weather(name: "ShangHai", temp: 14),
        Weather(name: "London", temp: 15),
        Weather(name: "Las Vegas", temp: 16),
    ]
}
```

I found if I simply change the **`VStack`** to **`LazyVStack`** in both **`CollapsedView()`** and **`ExpandedView()`**, the **`scrollTo()`** method works fine.

But in my project, for some reason I don't want to use **`LazyVStack`**, just want to use **`VStack`**.
Is there any way to make **`scrollTo()`** work in **`VStack`**?

Comment: Seems to work fine to me. Just changing the scrollPosition inside the PositionTest View updates the view and scroll position accorfingly. If you do something like this: @State private var scrollPosition: Weather.ID? = Weather.samples[4].id it brings me to the end of the view. Am I missing something maybe?

Comment: U could misunderstood me. Yes reading scroll position works fine, but when tap CollapsedView() to ExpandedView(), it doesn't scroll to the relative item because scrollTo() method doesn't work. For example, I scroll to the "London" in CollapsedView(), then tap it, it will jump to ExpandedView(), but doesn't scroll to "London" position, but the debug info shows the scrollPosition property is already "London", so the scrollTo() method in ExpandedView() seems doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that when you trigger the `onTapGesture` method for view switching, you did not modify the `scrollPosition`, so it cannot automatically slide to the specified position.
Please refer to the modification and try again.

```
.onTapGesture {
     scrollPosition = weather.id
     isTaped.toggle()
}
```

If this still doesn't work, try making the following modifications again:

```
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        proxy.scrollTo(scrollPosition, anchor: .center)
    }
}
```

This can work normally on my end, and I hope it can help you

Comment: Thanks. When I scroll, the scrollPosition property will change automatically. I found another way to solve this my issue. The scrollPosition is an optional property, if I want scrollTo() works in VStack under ScrollView, I need to unwrap it, but the wired thing is I don't need to unwrap and it can works in LazyVStack! So I think it's a bug.